# WebServiceTemplate send raw XML as content

Tags: java, web-services, spring, jaxb, spring-ws

I am using Spring-WS with JAXB.

Have the next code:

```
WebServiceTemplate template = (WebServiceTemplate) ctx.getBean("requestWsTemplate");
ObjectFactory f = new ObjectFactory();
Request r = f.createRequest();
r.setContent("<age>25</age>");
template.marshalSendAndReceive(r);
```

the `<age>` tag gets escaped to `&lt;age&gt;`

Is there a way to send it raw/unescaped?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, the point of using JAXB is to have `setAge(25)` method somewhere rather than creating XML manually. What is your use case?

Comment: I need the Content to be XML, my actual content is much bigger. The point is how can I keep the data unescaped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using JAXB.

After marshalling I replace the content in my marshalled content and then send over the network the modified content.

Answer (score 0):

I think Jaxb is not the way to go since it needs to have a correct java structure for the xml (mostly based on an XSD file). If you want to marshall something like this you'd better use [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) (or any other non-schema based marshaller of course) as a marshaller since that's not based on a schema.

At least, that's how I solved this a while ago :)

On the other hand, if you've got any influence on the receiving end, you can simply decode the given (encoded) xml by using XStream. Which makes it a bit easier on the client side.